# Why does this query return different results when in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

#### Synopsis

I've got a query with a `WHERE` clause that contains a condition that checks a NULLable column against a parameter that may be NULL, like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table
WHERE NullableColumn = @NullableParameter
```

From my understanding, SQL Server is supposed to evaluate `NULL = NULL` `non-NULL = NULL` as false always, meaning if `@NullableParameter` is NULL then the above query would return zero records.

That's the behavior I see when running the query in a query window, but when I use the same query in a stored procedure and when `@NullableParameter` is NULL it is returning all records where `NullableColumn` is NULL. In short, it seems like the sproc is saying `NULL = NULL` is true.

That's the problem/question is a nutshell. The actual `WHERE` clause is a bit more involved and is presented with more detail in the section below.

#### The Gritty Details

I have a database with a table called **StudyResults**. Each record is uniquely identified by a `StudyResultId` primary key field. There is also a `ParticipantId` field, that indicates the subject involved in the study, and `GroupId`, which identifies what group the subject belonged to, if any. If the study was a single-person study, `GroupId` is NULL. `ParticipantId` cannot be NULL.

I have a stored procedure that needs to update some records in the **StudyResults** table for a particular study, but here's the rub - if the study is single-person study then I need to just update that one row; if it was a group study I want to update all rows in **StudyResults** for that group, for that subject.

This isn't too hard to accomplish. The stored procedure is passed a `StudyResultId` and then runs the following T-SQL to determine the `GroupId` and `ParticipantId` values for that row:

```
DECLARE @GroupId INT, @ParticipantId INT
SELECT @GroupId = GroupId,
       @ParticipantId = ParticipantId
FROM StudyResults
WHERE StudyResult = @StudyResultId
```

Next, I create a CURSOR to enumerate the **StudyResults** records of interest. Note the `WHERE` clause, which says, "Give me the records where `StudyResultId` equals the `@StudyResultId` passed into the sproc *or* the `GroupId` and `ParticipantId` values line up with the `GroupId` and `ParticipantId` values for the **StudyResults** record of interest.

```
DECLARE resultsToEnumerate CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT StudyResultId
FROM StudyResults
WHERE StudyResult = @StudyResultId OR (GroupId = @GroupId AND ParticipantId= @ParticipantId)
```

If `@GroupId` is NULL, then comparing `GroupId = @GroupId` should *always* be false, right? Because for SQL Server, `NULL = NULL` is false, and `non-NULL = NULL` is false.

But here's what it gets weird - if I run the above statements from a query window and use a `@StudyResultId` for a single-person study the CURSOR contains what I expect - namely, a single record. However, if I put the exact same code in a stored procedure and run it the CURSOR contains all of the single-person studies for that participant! It's as if it is saying `@GroupId` is NULL, so I'll return all records where `GroupId` is NULL, but why? `NULL = NULL` should never return a record, right?

In fact, if I go into the sproc and change the `WHERE` clause and replace `GroupID = @GroupID` with `NULL = NULL` I see the same results - all single-person studies for the participant in question. So it clearly is evaluating `NULL = NULL` to true in the sproc (or ignoring it).

#### The Workaround

I can "fix" this in the stored procedure by adding an additional check in the parentheses to ensure `GroupId IS NOT NULL` like so:

```
WHERE ActivityID = @ActivityID OR (GroupID IS NOT NULL AND GroupID = @GroupID AND PatientID = @PatientID)
```

This is what I have done, but I am perplexed as to why the `WHERE` clause is being evaluated differently in my stored procedure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try altering the stored procedure in a session after setting ANSI_NULLS to ON.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

alter procedure procedureName 
...
```

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(v=SQL.80).aspx):

> For stored procedures, SQL Server uses
>   the SET ANSI_NULLS setting value from
>   the initial creation time of the
>   stored procedure. Whenever the stored
>   procedure is subsequently executed,
>   the setting of SET ANSI_NULLS is
>   restored to its originally used value
>   and takes effect. When invoked inside
>   a stored procedure, the setting of SET
>   ANSI_NULLS is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

add this line of code

```
>   WITH RECOMPILE
```

in the beggining of the procedure, it makes sure to build a new execution plan, not depending in the previous execution.